# R - How to update data frames by rows

Tags: r

I know that if I use c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), I can modify a data frame by column. But how can I change the values of rows in a data frame? For example, some equivalent of the following:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope', 'George Smith')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800, 32000)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2006-7-15'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
employ.data[2:3,] <- c('Test',11111,'2011-1-01')
```

That hopefully would provide output similar to this:

```
> employ.data
      employee salary  startdate
1     John Doe  21000 2010-11-01
2         Test  11111 2011-01-01
3         Test  11111 2011-01-01
4 George Smith  32000 2006-07-15
```

Of course, this is not valid code. But there should certainly be some equivalent. I've searched Google and found nothing

Comment: You have several problems here. First of all, you should specify `, stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating `employ.data` if you don't want to mess up with factors. Second of all, an R vector can't hold several types at the same time, while you need to have a `character`, `numeric` and `Date` classes at the same time. Other than that, your attempt was correct and if all of the columns were, for instance, `character`s it would have worked.

Comment: Normally in data analysis work, one does not change values in specific rows but according to some conditional logic or a merge/match with another df? Why `2:3`? I feel this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are asking for help with your *Y* solution which attempts to solve an *X* problem that you are not asking.